# @Html.HiddenFor causes null in HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Please see the code below:

```
 @model NHibernate.AspNet.Identity.IdentityRole
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administration/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    <div>
        Role name
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and the code below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(IdentityRole role)
        {
            Service.Update(role);
            TempData["Comment"] = "The record was updated";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Role.Id is always null in the controller.  Role.Description contains the correct value.

The Role will not update because Role.Id is null.  What is the problem?

Comment: can you add your model and Edit(int id) method?

Comment: @akerra, the model is IdentityRole from the NHibernate.ASPNET.Identity namespace.

Comment: Yes, but can you post the code for you model class?

Comment: @akerra, which model class?

Comment: Using an identity class as your model is generally not a good idea as MVC will have to instantiate and populate it when passing it into the action. Are you sure that the `IdentityRole` class is the same as outlined in the view and that it has a property identical (including case) to `Id`?

Comment: more interested to see the method where you initially bind the model to the view

Comment: Here is the IdentityRole class: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/IdentityRole.cs.  It looks like it does not even have an Id member.

Comment: The generic base class does. Are you certain of the namespace of `IdentityRole` in the action? There's an object with the same name in Microsoft's `Identity`...

Comment: @DiskJunky, yes if I hover above the Identity role reference in the Edit method; then it confirms it is the NHibernate one and not the Microsoft one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the base class, the `Id` property doesn't have a `public` setter and cannot be set by the model binder. See [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/DomainModel/EntityWithTypedId.cs)

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the useful reference.  So it is impossible to update a role - Is that correct?

Comment: @w0051977 I'm not sure but using the `Identity` object directly as the view model isn't the way to go. Ideally, you'd have a dedicated class to use as the view model and use its details to create/modify any identity settings from within the action. This allows you to have the ID in the `HiddenFor()` and have it posted back to you. What you do then would be the job for `Identity`

Comment: Thanks.  Creating a new view model worked.  Could you have a look at my other NHibernate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609997/set-update-cascade-delete-cascade-to-none-in-code ?

Comment: That question was removed it seems